# What is needed server-side to use ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to get started with ember; after reading all the documentation, now i'm trying to move the example todo app to a server;
In the example the app is configured for using the LS Adapter for local data;
if i want to use data from the server, what i need to handle the ember-data get request?
I'm a beginner in this; what i mean is: is needed some kind of servlet to deal with ember-data? Where the data should be stored on the server?

I spent hours on google but i still confused about this; can you provide some input to drive me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any web-server technology stack you like with Ember Data. Ember data is just the frontend 'module'/'component' used to send requests to that server depending on actions invoked by your ember app, so it can keep everything in sync.

You simply build a RESTful API for your Ember App to consume and make sure the JSON you return is in the format ember data expects.

You could look at [ember-rails](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails), a good starting point for rails-based ember apps with ember data.